# xcopy failed to copy

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe

I copied a directory using

```
xcopy /S DIR DIR2
```

However, instead of a new folder, I got the file `DIR2` without any extension, even though it said `86 File(s) copied`.

Help says that `/S` also copies subdirectories. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve most likely forgotten the `/I` switch.

> If Source is a directory or contains wildcards and Destination does
>   not exist, xcopy assumes Destination specifies a directory name and
>   creates a new directory. Then, xcopy copies all specified files into
>   the new directory. By default, xcopy prompts you to specify whether
>   Destination is a file or a directory.

If the folder didn’t exist you should’ve been prompted if the destination is a file or directory.

You might also be interested in the `/e` switch instead of `/s`, which copies all folders, even if they are empty.

There are a large amount of other parameters for `xcopy` you can find by using a `/?`. Seldom do my xcopies ever use `/s` by itself.

More information here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy